# Check if a device supports wireless charging

Tags: android

How can I programmatically find out if a device supports wireless charging? I would like to hide some preferences related to wireless charging on devices that don't support it.

It seems like an easy enough question, yet I wasn't able to find an answer to it.

Comment: No,there doesn't seem to be a way to find out whether the device supports it or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to check whether a phone supports wireless charging programmatically.

AS shown in the following link that you can convert Samsung Galaxy S2 to be charged wirelessly:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-Wireless-Charging-to-Your-Smartphone/

It's more of a hardware feature than a software feature.

There is an organization which is trying to create a global standard and then you will be able to check with "Qi" logo on the box.

Details can be found here: http://www.wirelesspowerconsortium.com/what-we-do/qi/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `BatteryManager` and check for the constant `BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS` . You have to check like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Comment: I know this already, but this only tells me if the device is connected to a wireless charger. I want to know if the device supports wireless charging at all.